# Bootstrap 2.3.2 collapse isn't auto collapsing previous panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, accordion

I'm using a Bootstrap Accordion feature on my website to handle a few different lists of instructions and minimize the space taken. It's working great except that it isn't collapsing the previous panel when a new one is clicked.

Here's my code. Is there any reason why it wouldn't auto-collapse? I have the `.in` class there on purpose, as I do want the top item open by default.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                <h3>Title of instructions</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <ol>
                    <li>some stuff</li>
                    <li>some more stuff</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                <h3>Another List of Instructions</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Click the &ldquo;Make a One-time Pledge&rdquo; button
                <ol>
                    <li>some stuff</li>
                    <li>some more stuff</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is way better: 
Html

```
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a>Collapsible Group Item Title</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    A body of panel
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

A little css:

```
     <style>
        .panel-heading a:after {
            font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
            content: "\e080";
            float: right;
            color: grey;
        }

        .panel-heading {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .panel-collapse {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

and few rows of js:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".panel-heading").click(function () {
                // auto collapse all
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".panel-collapse").hide();
                // toggle current
                $(this).parent().find(".panel-collapse").toggle();
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29212838/3384047), I checked my version of Bootstrap from the top of bootstrap.min.js.  Turns out I was running version 3.3.4, not 2.3.2.  Followed the docs for 3.3.4, and the accordion works now!